# How to overwrite a API Platform request data

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I need to change a structure of request's JSON. So created an event subscriber class which extract, convert and initialized new request:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use Exception;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class RequestPreDeserializerOnPost implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() : array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [
                'deserialize', EventPriorities::PRE_DESERIALIZE,
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestEvent $event
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function deserialize(RequestEvent $event) : void
    {

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $method = $request->getMethod();

        $resource = $request->attributes->get('_api_resource_class');

        if(!$event->isMainRequest() || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method) {
            return;
        }

        $data = $request->toArray();

        /* convert $data here */

        $request->initialize(
            $request->query->all(),
            $request->request->all(),
            $request->attributes->all(),
            $request->cookies->all(),
            $request->files->all(),
            $request->server->all(),
            json_encode($data)
        );

    }
}
```

But i got an error "Serialization for the format "html" is not supported."
(API Platform set-up to send response on `json-ld` and `json` formats only)

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to set request's format:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use Exception;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class RequestPreDeserializerOnPost implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() : array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [
                'deserialize', EventPriorities::PRE_DESERIALIZE,
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestEvent $event
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function deserialize(RequestEvent $event) : void
    {

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $method = $request->getMethod();

        $resource = $request->attributes->get('_api_resource_class');

        if(!$event->isMainRequest() || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method) {
            return;
        }

        $data = $request->toArray();

        /* convert $data here */

        $format = $request->getPreferredFormat();

        $request->initialize(
            $request->query->all(),
            $request->request->all(),
            $request->attributes->all(),
            $request->cookies->all(),
            $request->files->all(),
            $request->server->all(),
            json_encode($data)
        );

        $request->setRequestFormat($format);

    }
}
```